# How to change an audio file from 16 bit to 8 bit

Tags: audio, audacity

I`m trying to lower the size of an audio file and minimize the quality loss.

One of the way`s I had is to move from a 16-bit audio file to an 8 bit one.
The quality loss has come with no surprise but I was wondering if there is a way that I can Normalize and EQ the file in a way that the transition will be better

My Logic was to try to represent the sound in the 256 Possible integer values (or as close as possible) hence getting a better quality

Comment: Have you considered using [SoX](http://sox.sourceforge.net/Docs/Documentation). It can do that for you - and much more.

Comment: you are on the right track - to maximize fidelity you want your audio to be normalized such that it consumes the entire range of possible bits while still on 16 bits then after your conversion the 8 bit will be using its full range too ... update your question to indicate whether you are looking for a programmatic solution or just a one off which you can do using tools like audacity or such